# Erase all the numbers ai where 1 < i < n, in some order, such that the total cost is minimized

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I encountered this problem.But I could not come up with any solution except brute force.Please suggest some efficient algorithm.
You are given a sequence of n numbers A = (a1, a2, ..., an). At one step, you can erase any number except for the leftmost and the rightmost ones. Erasing number ai costs ai−1 ∗ ai+1. Your goal is to erase all the numbers ai where 1 < i < n, in some order, such that the total cost is minimized. Give an algorithm to accomplish your goal, with O(n^3) time complexity.

Comment: Is that "cost" in terms of time?  Since the cost is based on the *values* in the sequence, with no bounds given, then we have no way of proving anything about the cost.

Comment: What is wrong with brute force?  Since you can delete only one number at a time, you have to perform `n-2` individual deletions.  The cost is based on each individual number -- according to your notation, we have a fixed cost for the total process of reducing this to (a1, an).

Comment: @Prune Could he mean the cost is based on the neighbours? user1766481, did you mean `costs a[i−1] ∗ a[i+1]` ?

Comment: It is not fixed cost...cost varies based on values...He needs a dynamic programming based solution to achieve the mentioned time complexity. Brute force time complexity will be O(n!)

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes, that's what I'm asking OP to clarify.  If it's just that notation, then the question makes good sense.  If it's merely a round-about way to describe a simpler situation, the problem reduces to a triviality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let DP[a,b] be the solution to the problem "minimum cost to erase all elements in the range a to b, not including the end points a and b themselves".

I assume the cost to delete an element is the product of the entries before and after the element.

Then you can get an O(n^3) algorithm by thinking backwards and considering "what is the final entry erased?".  If the last entry erased is at position x it will cost A[a]*A[b], and previously we need to erase all entries between a and x, and all entries between x and b.  However, this is just another case of the original problem.

Therefore we can build up the DP table as normal based on the following recurrence:

```
DP[a,b] = A[a]*A[b] + min( DP[a,x] + DP[x,b] for x in range a+1..b-1 )
```

There are O(n^2) entries in the table, and it takes O(n) to compute each entry, for an overall O(n^3) complexity.